# Remove items dynamically from table/list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this delete method that works just fine, but it does not remove items from the list dynamically, but requires me to reload the page to be able to see the results.

#### delete method

```
  deleteRevision = (id) => {
    alert("Are you sure you want to delete {revisionID} ?")
    console.log(id)
    axios.delete("http://localhost:8080/lagbevakning/revision/delete?id=" + id)
  }
```

#### My table method

```
  finishedRevisionsList = () => {
    return(
      <div>
          <Table celled>
              <Table.Header>
                <Table.Row>
                  <Table.HeaderCell>  Status      </Table.HeaderCell>
                  <Table.HeaderCell>  Skapad      </Table.HeaderCell>
                </Table.Row>
              </Table.Header>

          {this.state.data.map((item, i) => (
                <Table.Body key={item.id}>
                  <Table.Row>
                    <Table.Cell>{item.status}</Table.Cell>
                    <Table.Cell> 
                          <i className="far fa-trash-alt" onClick={this.deleteRevision.bind(this, item.id)}></i>
                    </Table.Cell>
                  </Table.Row>
                </Table.Body>
          ))}
          </Table>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

#### Render

```
    render() {
        return (
          <div>
           {this.finishedRevisionsList()}
          </div>
        )
      }
```

Any suggestions on how i can get this table to be more dynamic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `deleteRevision` method just sends a `DELETE` request to the backend, but doesn't update the component state.

You could filter out the item with the given `id` from `data`.

```
deleteRevision = id => {
  axios.delete("http://localhost:8080/lagbevakning/revision/delete?id=" + id);

  this.setState(({ data }) => ({
    data: data.filter(item => item.id !== id)
  }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your data array in state after delete.

Answer (score 0):

You remove element from `this.state.data` after that you must set the new data to state(without the element you removed)

somthing like:

```
this.setStete((prevState) => {
  data: prevState.data.filter(item => item.id !== id);
);
```